# Can we use Player stats API for iOS?

Tags: ios, cocoapods, google-play-games

I want to segment the users based on how the users are engaging, spending etc. I found the android support for player stats API through the Google Play Services SDK: https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/stats#before_you_begin

I found that we install Google SDK with cocoa pods. I want to do the same for iOS: https://developers.google.com/ios/guides/cocoapods#add_a_google_sdk_to_your_ios_app.

Can I get the SDK without using cocoa pods? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Google Play Game Services SDK for iOS without Cocoapods.  See https://developers.google.com/games/services/ios/quickstart#option_2_manual_installation

Out of curiosity, why not use Cocoapods to manage the dependencies?